# quiero guardar el total de una compra en una linea de un archivo de texto

Tags: java

y siempre que se haga una compra se sume el valor que hay en el archivo de texto con el de la nueva compra y se vuelva a guardar en esa misma linea del archivo de texto
esto fue lo que intenté

```
try {
        pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(c,true));
        br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(c));
        String linea=br.readLine();
        Double corteCaja = null;
         if(linea==null)
         {
         pw.print(0);
         corteCaja+=Double.parseDouble(linea)+Double.parseDouble(Total);
         pw.print(corteCaja);
         }
         else
         {
             corteCaja+=Double.parseDouble(linea)+Double.parseDouble(Total);
             pw.print(corteCaja);
         }
        br.close();
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(factura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente es bueno usar el try-with-resources de Java moderno. En Java viejo si vas a abrir un archivo, SIEMPRE debes cerrarlo en un finally así:

```
try {
        pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(c,true));
        br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(c));
         
        ....
} catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(factura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
        if (null != br) br.close();
        if (null != pw) pw.close();
}
```

Pero esto es medio sucio y también genera más excepciones entonces la forma elegante de hacerlo es con Java moderno:

```
try(PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(c,true)) ) {
   try (BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(c)) ) {
         
        ....
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(factura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 
// ahora se cierra solo!
```

Ahora que hemos aclarado eso podemos escribir la solución:

```
try(PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(c,true)) ) {
   try (BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(c)) ) {

        double corteCaja = 0.0;
        String linea = br.readLine();
        
        if(linea!=null) {
             corteCaja =  Double.parseDouble(linea);
        }
        corteCaja += total;

        pw.println(corteCaja);
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(factura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 
// ahora se cierra solo!
```

Nota: no había razón de usar Double en este código así que lo implementé con double no más. Es mejor para hacer las sumas (más eficiente).